# Left Rotation on an Array

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question where I need to rotate an array left k times.

i.e. if k = 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] . -> [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]

So, my code is:

```
def array_left_rotation(a, n, k):
    for i in range(n):
        t = a[i]
        a[i] = a[(i+n-1+k)%n]
        a[(i+n-1+k)%n] = t

    return a
```

where n = length of the array.

I think the problem is a mapping problem, a[0] -> a[n-1] if k = 1.

What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: This problem almost surely can be easier solved with slicing.

Comment: Consider the case when `i==0` and `k==1` (the shift of the first element by one position to the right).  `a[i] = a[(i+n-1+k)%n]` becomes `a[0] = a[(0+n-1+1)%n]=a[n%n]=a[0]`. Is this right?

Comment: Have you tried `print`ing the value of `(i+n-1+k)%n` so as to verify that the elements that get swapped are the ones you expect to get swapped? Have you tried simulating the process with physical objects, to verify that swapping things in this manner produces the desired result?

Answer (score 18):

Another way to do this with the help of indexing is shown below..

```
def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

print(rotate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2))

#output : [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

This will only return the original list if n is outside the range `[-len(l), len(l)]`. To make it work for all values of n, use:

```
def rotate(l, n):
  return l[-n % len(l):] + l[:-n % len(l)]
```

Comment: Nice solution! Why is the minus sign (-n...) necessary, though?

Comment: In python, to index a list back wards you can use negative indices

Answer (score 5):

```
def leftRotation(a, d, n):
    i=0
    while i < n:
        print(a[(i+d)%n], end = ' ')
        i+=1
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    d = 4
    n = 7 or len(a)
    leftRotation(a, d, n)
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way rotate an array n times would be to use slicing,

```
def left_rotate(arr, n):
    # arr - array to rotate
    # n - n number of rotations
    # For number of rotations greater than length of array
    n = n % len(arr)
    return arr[n:] + arr[:n]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do is by using `collections.deque`

```
from collections import deque
k = 2
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dl = deque(l)
dl.rotate(k+1)
list(dl)
#[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Just a side note: Although your solution returns the specific result required in the question, according to the python doc `deque.rotate()` has to be called with a negative argument in order to rotate the items to left. The Left rotation was also part of the required behavior in the question.

Comment: btw. rotating `[1,2,3,4]` with your code returns  `[2, 3, 4, 1]` which is not the behavior asked for in the question. changing `dl.rotate(k+1)` into `dl.rotate(-1*k)` should fix your code

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotate_left(array, shift):
 length = len(array)
 overflow = length * (shift//length + 1)
 return [array[i+shift - overflow] for i in range(length)]
```

This works if you put in negative numbers, as well, so you can rotate right if you want.

The downside is that it's not in place rotation, so you get a new array, but since your solution returns an array, it makes more sense to leave the original array untouched.

The new index for items in the array is the current index, plus how far left you want to move (although this would actually move them right) minus how many times around the array this would take you plus one. The plus one forces the resulting index to be negative, so we go through the original array from the back.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Given an array Arr[ ] of N integers and a positive integer K. The task 
is to cyclically rotate the array clockwise by K. keep the first 
position of array unaltered. PYTHON**
```

```
def Rotate(arr, k, output):
    
    if not output: output.append(arr.pop(0))
    if len(arr)==k:
        for _ in range(k):
            if arr: output.append(arr.pop(-1))
    for i in range(k):
        if arr: output.append(arr.pop(0))
    if arr: Rotate(arr, k, output)
    return(output)

arr = [10,20,30]
k = 4
output = []
Rotate(arr, k, output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use GO to answer it. But you can take the logic from the code :

```
for i := d; i > 0; i-- {
    x := a[0]
    a = a[1:]
    a = append(a, x)
 }
 return a
```

First, `x := a[0]` take the value first value of array `a[0]`. Then, delete the array `a[0]` and push the first array `x` that you copied to last line in array a (in golang we use : `append(arr,element)`). And repeat it until `d` length.

if you using `i` in loop, it will make the code distracted. Because we only focus in array [0] (first array) and move it to last array while looping.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 5  #number of elements

    d = 4  #number of times left operation needs to be performed

    a = [1,2,3,4,5] #array to be rotated

    def leftRotate(a, n, d): 
        # To get the starting point of rotated array 
        mod = d % n 
        print(mod)


    # Prints the rotated array from start position 
        for i in range(n): 
            print (str(a[(mod + i) % n]), end = ' ')

(leftRotate(a, n, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotateLeft(rotation, arr):
    res = [None] * len(arr)
    rotation = rotation % len(arr)
    
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        index = i - rotation
        if index < 0:
            index = index + len(arr)
            
        res[index] = arr[i]
    
    return res
```

or

```
def rotateLeft(rotation, arr):
   return arr[rotation:] + arr[:rotation
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to left rotate array via recursion in golang:

```golang
func rotLeft(a []int32, d int32) []int32 {  
    if d==0{return a}
    newArr := make([]int32, len(a)-1)  
    copy (newArr, a[1:])
    newArr = append(newArr,a[0])
    return rotLeft(newArr, d-1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVA CODE:

public class Solution {

```
public static void rotate(int[] arr, int d) {
    //eg) n=6, d=4
    int n = arr.length;
    int k=0;
    
    //storing elements from index 0 to d-1
    //in temp array of size d
    
    int temp[] = new int [d];
    
    for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
        //1,3,6,11
    }
    
    //left rotating elements
    //storing from index 0 to n-d-1
    for(int i=0; i<n-d; i++)
    {
        
        //index: 0 and 1
        arr[i]=arr[d+i];
        //arr[0] = arr[4]
        //arr[1] = arr[5]
        
        //12, 17, 6,11,12,17
    }
    
    //copying temp array elements
    //in arr from index n-d to n-1
    
    for(int i=n-d; i<n; i++)
    {
        //index: 2, 3, 4,5
        arr[i] = temp[k];
        k++;
        //arr[2] = temp[0]
        //arr[3]=temp[1]
        //arr[4]=temp[2]
        //arr[5]=temp[3]
        
        //12, 17, 1,3,6,11
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Explanation:

1. First we copy the elements from 0 to d-1 in temp array
2. from index 0 to n-d-1, we move elements to the left
3. we replace the elements from index n-d to n-1, by copies stored in temp array

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using pop method

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] # The list
d = 3 # Number of rotations

# Pop the first element and append it at the end
for i in range(0, d):
    b = a.pop(0)
    a.append(b)

print(' '.join(map(str, a))) # print as space separated string
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution requires constant extra memory, and runs in O(nk).

If the array has zero length, or there are zero rotations, skip the loop and return arr.

For every rotation we store the first element, then shift every other element to the left, finally placing the first element at the back of the list. We save some work for large values of k by recognizing that every rotation after the nth is a repeat solution -> k % n.

```
def array_left_rotation(arr, n, k):
    for _ in range(0 if 0 in [n, k] else k % n):
        temp = arr[0]
        for idx in range(n - 1):
            arr[idx] = arr[idx + 1]
        arr[-1] = temp
    return arr
```

Comment: generally in Python you try to use the tools provided by the standard lib. This looks like an attempt to write low-level code in Python. It's rarely a good idea: It is hard to guess the memory requirement of an algorithm in Python (much harder than C), and I am not sure OP cares that much about "constant extra memory". Also, a consequence is that readability is low, which is considered important in Python.

Comment: This question is tagged data structures and algorithms, so I provided time and space complexity. If asked this question in an interview, space and runtime trade offs need to be addressed. This algorithm is O(1) time and runs in O(nk). The question was not “give me the most pythonic”. If you can’t read this, you need more practice.

Answer (score -1):

```
N, d = map(int, input().split())     #taking length N and no. of rotations d
a = list(input().split())            #taking input array as list
r = a[d % N : N] + a[0 : d % N]      #rotating the array(list)
print(r)  

5 2                            #giving N,D as input
1 2 3 4 5                      #giving input array
['3', '4', '5', '1', '2']      #output
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
temp=[]
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
  temp=nums[i]
  nums[i]=nums[i+1]
  nums[i+1]=temp

return nums
```

Comment: An ingenious solution! Please fix your indentation. Why is the function called `rotate_left3`? How would you deal with OP wanting to rotate the list `k` times?

Comment: Could you give an explanation of why the code works?

Answer (score -3):

This is how I did it:

```
def rotate_left3(nums):
    return [ nums[1] , nums[2] , nums[0] ]
```

It worked perfect 100%, but if you add more sums, you'd have to add its just set for the 3 that the problem specified.